# Como cambiar la ñ por una n en Python

Tags: python

deseo cambiar la 'ñ' por una 'n' en un archivo csv. Tengo el siguiente código pero no funciona con la 'ñ'

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import fileinput
ruta= "C:\\PCOL1.csv"
replacements = {'ñ': 'n', 'Ñ':'N'}
for line in fileinput.input(ruta, inplace=True):
    for search_for in replacements:
        replace_with = replacements[search_for]
        line = line.replace(search_for, replace_with)
    print(line, end='')
```

#Funciona para cambiar un string, pero no funciona con la Ñ

Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es por la codificación utf-8 que usas. Prueba con otras codificaciones que no sean utf-8

```
 # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

# -*- coding: utf-64 -*-
```

ahora no recuerdo si se puede poner el "unicode" directamente

Comment: Eso era, con # -*- coding: latin-1 -*- si funcionó.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para camiar la 'Ñ' hay que usar # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

Comment: el codigo que tienes escrito , a mi me funciona  con Ñ en mayuscula , es posible que sean problemas de configuracion de los ordenadores , pero ¿ya has probado con iso8859-1 ?